# Invalid argument key "nameOfTheArgument" found symfony3 (Extending an abstract service)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting the error *invalid argument key "articleBuilder"*, when I launch a console command from symfony3.

I have extended an abstract service, and I'm including the configurations and the classes code that I have used.

Given as the configuration of my parent class service:

```
app.service.user.access_controller:
        abstract: true
        class: '%app.service.user.access_controller.class%'
        arguments:
            currentUser: "@=service('security.token_storage').getToken().getUser()"
            userRoleProvider: '@app.repository.user.user_role_repository'
```

Where this is the parent service class:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Service\User;


    use AppBundle\Exception\User\AccessControlException;
    use AppBundle\ModelInterface\User\OwnableInterface;
    use AppBundle\ModelInterface\User\UserInterface;
    use AppBundle\ServiceInterface\User\UserRoleProviderInterface;

    /**
     * Class AccessController
     * @package AppBundle\Service\User
     */
    abstract class AccessController
    {
        /** @var UserInterface */
        protected $currentUser;

        /** @var UserRoleProviderInterface */
        protected $userRoleProvider;

        /**
         * AccessControlledService constructor.
         * @param UserInterface $currentUser
         * @param UserRoleProviderInterface $userRoleProvider
         */
        public function __construct(UserInterface $currentUser, UserRoleProviderInterface $userRoleProvider)
        {
            $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
            $this->userRoleProvider = $userRoleProvider;
        }
```

And where this is my child service definition:

```
    app.controller.article.article_json_api_controller:
            class: '%app.controller.article.article_json_api_controller.class%'
            parent: 'app.service.user.access_controller'
            arguments:
                articleBuilder: '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_entity.builder'
                articlePersister: '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_entity.persister'
                articleProvider: '@app.repository.article.article_repository'
                articleUpdater: '@app.service.article.updater'
                articleDestroyer: '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_entity.destroyer'
                languageProvider: '@app.repository.language.language_repository'
                sectionBuilder: '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_section_entity.builder'
                sectionUpdater: '@app.service.article.article_section.updater'
```

And this is my child service class:

```
class ArticleJsonApiController extends AccessController
{
    /** @var UserInterface */
    private $currentUser;

    /** @var ArticleBuilderInterface */
    private $articleBuilder;

    /** @var ArticlePeristerInterface */
    private $articlePersister;

    /** @var ArticleProviderInterface */
    private $articleProvider;

    /** @var ArticleUpdaterInterface */
    private $articleUpdater;

    /** @var ArticleDestroyerInterface */
    private $articleDestroyer;

    /** @var LanguageProviderInterface */
    private $languageProvider;

    /** @var ArticleSectionBuilderInterface */
    private $sectionBuilder;

    /** @var ArticleSectionUpdaterInterface */
    private $sectionUpdater;

    /**
     * ArticleJsonApiController constructor.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $currentUser
     * @param UserRoleProviderInterface $userRoleProvider
     * @param ArticleBuilderInterface $articleBuilder
     * @param ArticlePeristerInterface $articlePersister
     * @param ArticleProviderInterface $articleProvider
     * @param ArticleUpdaterInterface $articleUpdater
     * @param ArticleDestroyerInterface $articleDestroyer
     * @param LanguageProviderInterface $languageProvider
     * @param ArticleSectionBuilderInterface $sectionBuilder
     * @param ArticleSectionUpdaterInterface $sectionUpdater
     */
    public function __construct(
        UserInterface $currentUser,
        UserRoleProviderInterface $userRoleProvider,
        ArticleBuilderInterface $articleBuilder,
        ArticlePeristerInterface $articlePersister,
        ArticleProviderInterface $articleProvider,
        ArticleUpdaterInterface $articleUpdater,
        ArticleDestroyerInterface $articleDestroyer,
        LanguageProviderInterface $languageProvider,
        ArticleSectionBuilderInterface $sectionBuilder,
        ArticleSectionUpdaterInterface $sectionUpdater
    ) { 
            parent::__construct($currentUser, $userRoleProvider);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem does not lie with `articleBuilder` itself, but rather with your intention to define the arguments as an associative array.

If I am not mistaken, when dealing with `parent` services, you have at your disposal a special `index_N` key which serves to override the value of some argument already defined in your parent service. Therefor, I think, you need to define your argument in way that looks like this:

```
app.controller.article.article_json_api_controller:
    class: '%app.controller.article.article_json_api_controller.class%'
    parent: 'app.service.user.access_controller'
    arguments: 
        - '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_entity.builder'
        - '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_entity.persister'
        - '@app.repository.article.article_repository'
        - '@app.service.article.updater'
        - '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_entity.destroyer'
        - '@app.repository.language.language_repository'
        - '@app.service.article.doctrine_orm.article_section_entity.builder'
        - '@app.service.article.article_section.updater'
```

Hope this helps a bit...

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what `parent` services are. AFAIK you're trying to map 1-to-1 your parent abstract class as an abstract service, but parent services are used differently in Symfony, i.e. to manage common dependencies for several classes.

Reference: [How to Manage Common Dependencies with Parent Services - Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html)